# tf.data API cannot print all the batches

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, tensorflow-datasets

I am self-teaching myself about `tf.data` API. I am using `MNIST` dataset for binary classification. The training x and y data is zipped together in the full train_dataset. Chained along together with this zip method is first the `batch()` dataset method. the data is batched with a batch size of 30. Since my training set size is 11623, with batch size 128, I will have 91 batches. The size of the last batch will be 103 which is fine since this is LSTM. Additionally, I am using drop-out. When I compute batch accuracy, I am turning off the drop-out.

The full code is given below:

```
#Ignore the warnings
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (8,7)

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/")

Xtrain = mnist.train.images[mnist.train.labels < 2]
ytrain = mnist.train.labels[mnist.train.labels < 2]

print(Xtrain.shape)
print(ytrain.shape)

#Data parameters
num_inputs = 28
num_classes = 2
num_steps=28

# create the training dataset
Xtrain = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(Xtrain).map(lambda x: tf.reshape(x,(num_steps, num_inputs)))
# apply a one-hot transformation to each label for use in the neural network
ytrain = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(ytrain).map(lambda z: tf.one_hot(z, num_classes))
# zip the x and y training data together and batch and Prefetch data for faster consumption
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((Xtrain, ytrain)).batch(128).prefetch(128)

iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(train_dataset.output_types,train_dataset.output_shapes)
X, y = iterator.get_next()

training_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(train_dataset)


#### model is here ####

#Network parameters
num_epochs = 2
batch_size = 128
output_keep_var = 0.5

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()

    print("Initialized")
    # Training cycle
    for epoch in range(0, num_epochs):
        num_batch = 0
        print ("Epoch: ", epoch)
        avg_cost = 0.
        avg_accuracy =0
        total_batch = int(11623 / batch_size + 1)
        sess.run(training_init_op)
       while True:
            try:
                _, miniBatchCost = sess.run([trainer, loss], feed_dict={output_keep_prob: output_keep_var})
                miniBatchAccuracy = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={output_keep_prob: 1.0})
               print('Batch %d: loss = %.2f, acc = %.2f' % (num_batch, miniBatchCost, miniBatchAccuracy * 100))
                num_batch +=1
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                break
```

When I run this code, it seems it is working and printing:

```
Batch 0: loss = 0.67276, acc = 0.94531
Batch 1: loss = 0.65672, acc = 0.92969
Batch 2: loss = 0.65927, acc = 0.89062
Batch 3: loss = 0.63996, acc = 0.99219
Batch 4: loss = 0.63693, acc = 0.99219
Batch 5: loss = 0.62714, acc = 0.9765
......
......
Batch 39: loss = 0.16812, acc = 0.98438
Batch 40: loss = 0.10677, acc = 0.96875
Batch 41: loss = 0.11704, acc = 0.99219
Batch 42: loss = 0.10592, acc = 0.98438
Batch 43: loss = 0.09682, acc = 0.97656
Batch 44: loss = 0.16449, acc = 1.00000
```

However, as one can see easily, there is something wrong. Only 45 batches are printed not 91 and I do not know why this is happening. I tried so many things and I think I am missing something out.

I can use `repeat()` function but I do not want that because I have redundant observations for last batches and I want LSTM to handle it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an annoying pitfall when defining a model based directly on the `get_next()` output of a `tf.data` iterator. In your loop, you have two `sess.run` calls, *both* of which will advance the iterator by one step. This means each loop iteration actually consumes two batches (and also your loss and accuracy calculations are computed on different batches).

Not entirely sure if there is a "canonical" way of fixing this, but you could

- compute the accuracy in the same `run` call as the cost/training step. This would mean that the accuracy calculation is also affected by the dropout mask, but since it's an approximate value based on only one batch, that shouldn't be a huge issue.
- define your model based on a placeholder instead, and in each loop iteration `run` the `get_next` op itself, then feed the resulting numpy arrays (i.e. the batch) into the loss/accuracy computations.

Comment: Yes, actually I tried both approaches. For the second approach, I particularly did not want to use placeholders because my next step will be to use `tf.data` API with a SQL query and I want to avoid using feed_dict to consume the data because the result of this SQL query is big.

After I asked this question, I realized I cannot do two `ses.run` calls so I put the accuracy in the same `run` call as the cost/training step, as this is the first approach you mention and it works. I think this approach is more feasible and I can calculate accuracies of each batches for a model with drop-out

Comment: What are the other approaches though to use `tf.data` API to define a model? it is either assigning output of a `tf.data` iterator to each arguments of a model definition OR to use the `feed_dict` to consume the output of `sess.run([X,y])` (or `sess.run(next_batch)`) like given in [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-dataset-in-tensorflow-c758ef9e4428) or [here](https://github.com/kratzert/finetune_alexnet_with_tensorflow/blob/d428d1ede22aba6ae4d66fc6cc03a10f7a9ddc81/finetune.py#L169).

Comment: I don't think there is any other "direct" way, since after all `tf.data` iterators just return tensors and the `get_next` op will advance each time it is called... One option could be to define a custom dataset that returns each element twice (or `k` times, which can be given as a parameter) before advancing. This could e.g. be achieved via a dataset `from_generator`.